# How to filter maximum count of occurrence of a value in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query:

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(product_id) CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
FROM Order_Details
Group BY customer_id, product_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

which results in following table:

```
    CUSTOMER_I PRODUCT_ID CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------------------
C1         P3                              2
C1         P4                              1
C2         P5                              1
C3         P2                              4
C3         P3                              1
C3         P4                              1
C4         P1                              3
C4         P6                              1
C5         P6                              1

9 rows selected.
```

I am having problem in filtering out the maximum occurance of each customer's product id which would look like

```
CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------------------
C1         P3                              2
C2         P5                              1
C3         P2                              4
C4         P1                              3
C5         P6                              1
```

occurrence of count 1 may or may not be omitted for customer_id other than C1 and C3. Only

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to assign each record a number that designates the order of the record depending on the count for each customer and then filter on that.

```
SELECT customer_id,
       product_id,
       customer_product_count
       FROM (SELECT customer_id,
                    product_id,
                    count(product_id) customer_product_count,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                       ORDER BY count(product_id) DESC) r
                    FROM order_details
                    GROUP BY customer_id,
                             product_id
                    ORDER BY customer_id) x
       WHERE r = 1;
```

If you want to include ties, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: This was exactly what the answer is

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in Oracle is two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id, CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT,
       MAX(product_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT DESC) as product_id
FROM (SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(*) AS CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
      FROM Order_Details
      GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
     ) cp
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

The `KEEP` expression is Oracle's way of defining a "first()" aggregation function.